# How to deserialize this json to a list of objects?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I got this Json msg (don't pay attention to the encoding) :

```
{
"U1000 R2V": {
    "carac1": ["CÃ¢ble d'alimentation rigide rond"],
    "optionVJ": ["Oui"],
    "carac4": [""],
    "carac3": ["Pour alimentation de ligne Ã©lectrique", "Pour alimentation des moteurs"]
},
"H05 VVF": {
    "carac1": ["CÃ¢ble souple rond"],
    "optionVJ": ["Oui"],
    "carac4": [""],
    "carac3": ["Pour cÃ¢blage des sÃ©lecteurs Ã  clÃ©", "Pour alimentation des lampe clignotantes"]
}
}
```

I've tried with those objects :

```
public class TypeProductList
{
    public List<ProductTypeDTO> cables { get; set; }
}


public class ProductTypeDTO
{
    public string[] carac1;
    public string[] optionVJ;
    public string[] carac4;
    public string[] carac3;
}
```

But this doesn't work, actually i don't know how to do because the "parent element" (i mean U1000 R2V, H05 VVF) is changing for every object.
What structure should i use to deserialize this to a List of ProductTypeDTO?
Thx

Comment: try to use public Dictionary<string,ProductTypeDTO> cables { get; set; } and when deserialized convert to any type of object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Anton noted in his comment, you should deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, ProductTypeDTO>` first.

Code (uses JSON.NET):

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, ProductTypeDTO>>(json);
var typeProductList = new TypeProductList { cables = result.Values.ToList(); }
```